# How to use whereIn for column array?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have data from a table structured like so:

```json
table: students
{
  id:
  name:
  classes: [
    {
      name: "gym"
    },
    {
     name: "science"
    },
    {
     name: "math"
    },
    {
     name: "english"
    }
  ]
}
reference array: science, math
```

How do I return only records that match the values found in the reference array. For example, if the reference array contains math and science then all records returned from the student table will need to have those values in the classes array name field.

I'm trying to use whereIn, but it does not accept a column (array) and field as the first parameter.

Comment: you should use whereIn in this way: ->whereIn('classes', ['science','math'])

Comment: classes is an array of objects. This does not work.

Comment: could you please post the migration for the student table or the whole query you are executing? i would like to know if that "classes" come from a single table or from a join or similar.

Comment: Classes comes from another table using "with()" function.

Comment: please add model and controller in your question

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
Student::select("*")->whereIn('classes', $referencearray)
                    ->get();
```